# Not showing the correct value at the address given by pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I am making an error somewhere at the last line. It is not showing the correct value at the address.

```
   /* an array with 5 elements */
   double balance[5] = {1000.0, 2.0, 3.4, 17.0, 50.0};
   double backup[5];
   double *p;
   double address;

   int i = 0;

   memcpy(&backup, &balance, sizeof(balance));
   p = backup;

   /* output each array element's value */
   printf( "Array values using pointer\n");
   for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
   {
       //printf("*(p + %d) : %f\n",  i, *(p + i) );
       printf("&p[%d] : %f\n",  i,  p[i]);
       printf("&p[%d] : address: %p\n",  i,  (void*)(&p+i));
   }

   int offset = 4;
   printf("Contents of &p[%d] : address: %x is %f\n",  offset,  ((&p)+(offset)), p[offset]);
   double* newPointer;
   newPointer = ((&p)+(offset));
   printf("The content again: %f at address: %x\n",  *(newPointer), newPointer);
```

// output is incorrect

The content again:  **0.000000**  at address: 28feec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
memcpy(backup, balance, sizeof(balance));
p = backup;

printf( "Array values using pointer\n");
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
    //printf("*(p + %d) : %f\n",  i, *(p + i) );
    printf("p[%d] : %f\n",  i,  p[i]);
    printf("p[%d] : address: %p\n",  i,  (void*)(p+i));
}

int offset = 4;
printf("Contents of p[%d] : address: %p is %f\n",  offset,  p+offset, p[offset]);
double* newPointer;
newPointer = p+offset;
printf("The content again: %f at address: %p\n",  *newPointer, newPointer);
```

Comment: Laziness is virtue of a programmer.

Answer (score 4):

Just from the typing I'd say, this:

```
newPointer = ((&p)+(offset));
```

should be:

```
newPointer = p + offset;
```

This:

```
((&p)+(offset))
```

returns a `double **`, as you take the address of a `double *`. Adding to this any offset still leaves it a `double **`. This you surely would not like to assign to a `double *`.

> I am making an error somewhere at the last line

This mistake of taking the address of `p` is also made at several other location before "*the last line*".

---

And to point this out again:

To print out a pointer's value cast it to `void *` (if it isn't one already) and use the `p` conversion specifier:

```
printf("The content again: %f at address: %p\n",  *newPointer, (void *) newPointer);
```

Using `x` or `d` or `i` offers you a fair chance to lose half of the address' significant bits.

Answer (score 2):

`double *p`; Here `p` itself is a address locating pointer `p`. So while adding an offset just do, `p + offset`

Here is an diagrammatic representation how pointer behaves. `p` is a pointer pointing/holding address of `backup`. So `p` has address `0x2000` but `&p` is address of `p` which is `0x3000`. Therefore `&p + offset` leads to different memory location which is happening in your case.

```
   p                  backup              
+------+             +------+          
|      |             |      |                        
|0x2000|------------>|0x1000| 
|      |             |      |
+------+             +------+
 0x3000               0x2000
```

Also use,

`%p` format specifier for pointer addresses.